# How to use list of border pixels to obtain list of inside pixels?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have an image that I have contoured using the active_contour method from skimage. However, I need to find the average of the pixels within the image. The border created by the contour is multiple pixels thick and has an irregular closed shape.

I am able to obtain a list of all the border pixels. Is there a way to use this list to find the locations of all the pixels inside the border(despite it being multiple pixels thick)?

Comment: Draw a white filled contour on a black background using OpenCV. Then get the coordinates of all white pixels from that image using numpy.argwhere().

Comment: Sounds very interesting. It's a shame we can see neither your image nor your code.